# adding a custom variable as a tooltip in highcharts scatter chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm struggling with adding a custom variable to a tooltip in my highcharts scatter chart.

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'scatter',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: 'First: {point.x}, Second: {point.y}'
            }, 


  xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
           day: '%m/%d'    //ex- 01 Jan 2016
        }
    },
yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        plotLines: [
                        {
                value:2019,
                color: 'grey',
                /* dashStyle: 'shortdash', */
                width: 0.5},
                {
                value:2018,
                color: 'grey',
                /* dashStyle: 'shortdash', */
                width: 0.5},

                ]
    },

  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
    },
   },

  series: [{}],
}

var data = {
  "other": [
    {
      "y": 2018,
      "x": "03/22/19",
      "contact_notes": "aa"
    },
    {
      "y": 2019,
      "x": "06/22/19",
      "contact_notes": "bb"
    },
    {
      "y": 2019,
      "x": "09/06/19",
      "contact_notes": "cc"
    }
  ],
}


var data2 = data['other']

data2.forEach(function(point) {
  point["x"] = new Date(point["x"]).getTime();
});

options.series[0].data = data2;
options.series[0].name = 'other'
options.series[0].color =  '#b20000' 

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

If you look at my data object, it has a key called 'contact_notes', I'd like to be able to see that data (i.e. see 'aa', 'bb','cc') in addition to the x and y points when I mouseover the three data points on the chart

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom properties end up in the options on the point, i.e. this would work:

```
pointFormat: 'First: {point.x}, Second: {point.y}, Third: {point.options.contact_notes}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointFormat` option or `formatter` function and get the custom property by `point.contact_notes`:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: 'First: {point.x}, Second: {point.y}, Third: {point.contact_notes}'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b2v6jfpt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat